# How do you destructure a React useState hook into a namespace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a personal preference I wrap React props in namespaces. It helps me organize where different props come from.

With the `useState` hook I'm doing this.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [todoCount, setTodoCount] = useState(100);
  const [doneCount, setDoneCount] = useState(0);
  const myState = {
    todoCount,
    setTodoCount,
    doneCount,
    setDoneCount
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Todo {myState.todoCount}</Text>
      <Text>Done {myState.doneCount}</Text>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there a more succinct syntax for state setup?

My failed attempt was

```
const myState = {
  [todoCount, setTodoCount]: useState(100),
  [doneCount, setDoneCount]: useState(0);
};
```

Comment: You can omit `: count` and `: setCount` at least, not sure it gets much more terse than that though

Comment: Well you could inline the second line e.g. `const myState = { count, setCount }`... although I presume you mean a way of doing both in one line, custom hook? `useNamespaceState` (not _really_ gaining anything here though IMO)

Comment: @CollinD I had actually done that in the first section but not the second. Should have copy/pasted.  Edited... thanks.

Comment: Why not use as it is as Array? Or at least maybe create your own hook, that will convert to object?

Comment: @James Yeah... I was hoping for a one liner so I can initiate all the state inside the `myState` namespace. Updated the example to be a little more complex to show this detail.

Comment: Sorry for a silly question but why don’t you just use statefull component without hooks instead?

Comment: @delmin https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the type of thing you could do as part of a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) e.g.

```
 function useMappedState(defaultState = {}) {
   const keys = Object.keys(defaultState);
   return keys.reduce((map, k) => {
     const fk = `set${k.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${k.slice(1)}`;
     const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState[k]);
     map[k] = state;
     map[fk] = setState;
     return map;
   }, {});
 }
 ...
 const state = useMappedState({
   todoCount: 100,
   doneCount: 0
 });
 console.log(state.todoCount) // 100
 state.setTodoCount(5); // should set state of todoCount
```

<strike>In *theory*, this should give you what you want, but I've not tested so use with caution (e.g. I'm not even sure if hooks can be called can be called inside an iterator).</strike> - this [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/69g5rc28/).

Although, what you are doing is *really* similar to what [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) already does, might be worth some experimenting with that hook instead.

Comment: This works great. Thank you. 
Typescript and ESLint don't love it but it's exactly what I asked! 

Answer (score 0):

When you need to manage complex state, [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) is the goto. It is a hook which accepts a reducer function in addition to initial state. The reducer is written by you to map certain "actions" to changes in state. You can "dispatch" an action to the reducer function to update state according to the rules you specify. `useState` itself internally calls `useReducer`.

```js
/* action = { type: string, payload: any type } */

function reducer(state, { type, payload }) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'do-todo':
      return { doneCount: state.doneCount + 1, todoCount: state.todoCount - 1 }
    case 'undo-todo':
      return { doneCount: state.doneCount - 1, todoCount: state.todoCount + 1 }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function App() {
  const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, { todoCount: 100, doneCount: 0 }) 

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Todo {state.todoCount}</Text>
      <Text>Done {state.doneCount}</Text>
      <Button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'do-todo' })}>Do Todo</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can use multiple reducers to map to multiple namespaces.