# Two way binding more than one input in React w/ Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I got two inputs. If I want to bind the input value with a state variable, 
I use this -

The state :

```
 const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
 const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState('')
```

The methods the bind them :

```
 const handleMessageChange = (e) => setMessage(e.target.value)
 const handleUserChange = (e) => setNewUser(e.target.value)
```

And I call these methods with the onChange property on the input.

My qusetion :

Can I use a generic handleChange method instead of explicitly creating a method to each input/state pair? If so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951398/3662110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider store both `user` and `message` in one `{data}` state holder, and at `handleChange` modified just the relevant key in state object

---

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({user: "", message: ""})

  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })), []);

  <input name="message" value={data.message} onChange={handleChange} />
  <input name="user" value={data.user} onChange={handleChange} />
```

---

Comment: Hi, Where is setData coming from?

Comment: sorry, had a typo..
anyhow editing my answer with bit explaintion

Answer (score 3):

Here's 2 ways to do so: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-pine-zgwfy

Illustrating one of the ways here.

The hooks and handler:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState("");
const handleChange = e =>
    e.target.name === "message"
        ? setMessage(e.target.value)
        : e.target.name === "user"
        ? setNewUser(e.target.value)
        : "";
```

The inputs:

```
<input name="message" value={message} onChange={handleChange} />
<input name="user" value={newUser} onChange={handleChange} />
```

Hope that helps,

Cheers!