# How to change color onClick on every icon seperatly? React, styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am learning react and styled-components. I am stack trying to change color on every icon seperatly. Is there any solution for this?

Here is what I want to get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsANO.jpg

Here is sample of my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  GiSteak,
  GiCheeseWedge,
  GiFlatfish,
  GiChickenOven,
  GiBroccoli,
} from "react-icons/gi";

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  div {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #828282;
    color: ${({ color }) => (color ? "green" : "lightGrey")};
  }
`;

const Selections = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);
  return (
    <StyledDiv color={color} onClick={() => setColor(!color)}>
      <p>Select your options</p>
      <div>
        <GiBroccoli />
        <GiCheeseWedge />
        <GiSteak />
        <GiFlatfish />
        <GiChickenOven />
      </div>
    </StyledDiv>

  );
};
```

Comment: Upvote for adding a sandbox, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually asking how to handle multiple states (hence not related to `styled-components`), as for now you have a single state for all icons, where you need a state per icon.

Here is one possible solution, managing a single array of icons states:

```
const Icon = styled.div`
  background-color: ${({ isColored }) => (isColored ? "green" : "lightGrey")};
`;

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 500px;
  .icon__box {
    display: flex;
    ${Icon} {
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
`;

const Icons = () => {
  const [areColored, setColor] = useState(Array(5).fill(false));
  console.log(areColored);
  return (
    <StyledDiv>
      <p>Select your options</p>
      <div className="icon__box">
        {areColored.map((isColored, index) => (
          <Icon
            key={index}
            isColored={isColored}
            onClick={() =>
              setColor((prev) => {
                const res = Object.assign([], prev, { [index]: !prev[index] });
                return res;
              })
            }
          >
            icon {index + 1}
          </Icon>
        ))}
      </div>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit agitated-neumann-3xy0m]

- [See similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950538/is-there-a-generic-way-to-set-state-in-react-hooks-how-to-manage-multiple-state/56950637#56950637)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can make use of `icon` state which stores an object structure like `{index:1,color:true}`. Combining this with the `nth-child(...)` css selector will allow you to accomplish your task like so :-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 500px;
  .icon__box{
    display: flex;
    div {
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      background-color:lightgrey
    }
    div:nth-child(${({icon})=>icon.index+1}){
      background-color: ${({ icon }) => (icon.color ? "green" : "lightGrey")};
    }
  }
`;

const Icons = () => {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState({index:0,color:false});
  const [icons] = useState(['icon1','icon2','icon3','icon4','icon5']);
  const handleClick=(index)=>{
     let newIcon = {...icon}
     newIcon.color = index!==newIcon.index?true:!newIcon.color;
     newIcon.index = index;
     setIcon(newIcon);
  }

  return (
    <StyledDiv icon={icon}>
      <p>Select your options</p>
      <div className="icon__box">
        {icons.map((icon,index)=>(<div onClick={()=>handleClick(index)}>{icon}</div>))}
      </div>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
};

export default Icons;
```

Here's is the forked one :-

[image: Edit jolly-wright-spum4]

**Note : Here I have made an `icons` state for the text content of each of your icon div. It will work the same way if you derive the above from `props`. So it's upto you**.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question. I am new to programming.

Comment: Ahh I see. You have updated your question..@Dennis solution should work I think.