# Différence between only one state for variables or state for every one in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

If i'm having 3 variables to handle with useState in react is doing this:

```
const [ user , setUser ] = useState({
name : '',
phone : '',
age : ''
})
setUser({...user, phone: value})
```

Or this :

```
const [ phone , setPhone] = useState('')
const [ name , setPName] = useState('')
const [ age , setAge] = useState('')

setPhone(value)
```

Is there any différence in term of performance ?
Which approach is more appropriate ?

Comment: Don't worry about the performance until you can measure it and see an actual difference. Use which ever one you prefer.

Comment: It doesnt matter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950538/is-there-a-generic-way-to-set-state-in-react-hooks-how-to-manage-multiple-state/56950637#56950637

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use them. If you use it in a form, it might be more convenient to have them in a single object. Technically, react has a watcher system that will only update what needs to be updated and therefore not re-render what hasn't changed. Here is a [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) to the official documentation that can help you understand when to use object based vs single state elements.

Answer (score 0):

to manage complex and nested objects and also if you have lots of states, it's better to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) like this:

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';
const initialState = { name: '', phone: '', age: 0 };

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'name':
      return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    case 'phone':
      return { ...state, phone: action.payload };
    case 'age':
      return { ...state, age: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const LoginPage = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const onChangeNameHandler = (e) => {
    dispatch({type: 'name', payload: e.target.value})
  }
  return (
    <input value={state.name} onChange = {onChangeNameHandler} />
  )
}
```

And then you have all states in "state" that we define at first
ex:

```
console.log(state.name) // name
```

I suggest you read this article that compares both useReducer and useState [here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/use-state-vs-use-reducer).